# compartilhar valor private com outro atributo na mesma classe

Tags: php

Tenho a seguinte classe modelo abaixo:

```
class modelo {
  private $variavel1 = "Algum";
  private $variavel2 = $this->variavel1." Valor";
  .....
}
```

Como anexar o valor da **variável1** ao valor **variavel2** sendo ambos da mesma classe?

Obs.: ***NÃO*** gostaria de receber esse valor pelo método construtor nem métodos (mágicos ou não)!

Será que tem jeito?

Comment: Pode fazer isso no construtor (sem receber o valor mesmo). Fora de um método isso é impossível.

Comment: Está usando OO, utilize get/set. No get da variável 2, retorna o valor da 1.

Comment: pois é. Eu NÃO gostaria de usar nem o construtor nem métodos mágicos. Então não deve ter jeito mesmo! Pensei que por estarem ambos atributos dentro da mesma classe haveria um recurso para isso!

Comment: Por quê não quer usar o construtor para inicializar os campos?

Comment: porque a classe é grande e eu não gostaria de escrever os mesmos atributos 2 vezes, (declaração e construtor). Penso que ficaria mais limpa a classe. Já que é impossível recuperar um private de fora da classe então de dentro deveria ser possivel